# Query the second highest value of a name, if there's only one value return null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has 2 columns, named "Name" and "Score", demonstrates the academic result of a class.

"Name": Andy, Amy, Chloe, John, etc.

"Score": From 0 to 100

Some of the students had submitted all the tests but some have not done yet due to pandemic, in other words, there's some student only got only 1 result.
Now I need to figure out what is the second-highest score that each of them has made.

If the students only submitted once, means that they don't have the second-highest score so we will return null for the score.

I tried

```
SELECT 
name,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(score) IS NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE MAX(score)
    END AS second_highest
FROM
    result
WHERE
    score NOT IN (SELECT 
            MAX(score)
        FROM
            result
        GROUP BY name)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name;
```

But seems like the subquery excluded the only score of the one-submission students, so they don't show up on the query result.
Is there anything I need to change in this method or is there any better approach?

[Input and output can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsqCy.png) sorry I am not familiar with demonstrating sample on Stackoverflow
I use MySQL version 8.0.22

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO and desired output for it. Specify **precise** MySQL version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to rank the scores for each student and then get the 2nd highest score with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN score END) second_highest
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY score DESC) rn
  FROM result
) t
GROUP BY name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4241a45450c0f709fe7489547ad8fb5e).